# ImportError while importing from any subdirectory of parent directory

Tags: python

I have a folder structure below

```
my_project
  -- main.py
  -- dept_1
      -- process.py
      -- ops.py
  -- dept_2
      -- process.py
      -- ops.py
  -- common
      -- utils.py
      -- config.py
      -- meta_data.py
```

Now I have 2 decorators defined in `utils.py`. Now I want to use those inside `ops.py` which is again called from `process.py`.

I have used the following code.

**in process.py**

```
from dept_1 import ops.py
from common import utils
# to import some other functions
```

**in ops.py**

I have used all the below options

```
from common import utils
from common.utils import *
from common.utils import decorator_1, decorator_2
```

but every time, I face some import error, saying either

> ImportError: No Module named 'utils'

or

> utils has no attribute 'decorator_1

or

> ImportError: can not import name 'decorator_1'

How to solve this issue?

Comment: Rather than relying on manipulating `sys.path` manually. It may be helpful to read through https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132789/relative-imports-for-the-billionth-time . This really helped me structure projects better so relative imports actually worked.

Comment: That being said, have you tried `import common.utils as utils` and `import dept_1.ops as ops`?

Comment: @Axe319, Yes I tried `import common.utils as utils` but this shows an attribute error: module 'common' has no attribute 'utils'.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `sys.path` variable by adding the path to the `utils.py` module to it:

```
import sys

sys.path.append('<your-path>')
```

Note: you have to add the absolute path to the `utils.py`

Or you can add a relative path like this:

```
import sys
    
sys.path.append('../common/')
```

Note: you must add the path in the file in which you want to use the `utils` module

Now all you need to do is to import utils in your file and the interpreter will find it:

```
import sys
import utils       
sys.path.append('../common/')
```